# Can't install pytorch with pip3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch, word-embedding

I want to install torch version 1.2.0, as I want to use biobert-embeddings, which seems to require pytorch 1.2.0, as when I am trying to install biobert-embeddings using
`pip3 install biobert-embedding`, I am getting an error saying

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.4.0, 1.4.0+cpu, 1.4.0+cu100, 1.4.0+cu92, 1.5.0, 1.5.0+cpu, 1.5.0+cu101, 1.5.0+cu92, 1.5.1, 1.5.1+cpu, 1.5.1+cu101, 1.5.1+cu92, 1.6.0, 1.6.0+cpu, 1.6.0+cu101, 1.6.0+cu92)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0

When I am trying to install torch==1.2.0, am getting the same error.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Python 3.8. `torch` 1.2 officials runs on Python up to 3.7.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:

```
> pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

This works in my environment.